# How to mix parameter strings in powershell

Tags: powershell, quotes, double-quotes

I need to pass some parameters to this start-process command in powershell. So far have been unable to make it work passing the parameters to the application. Seems like I cannot enclose in quotes my parameters to the application, without them, the command works fine.

```
Start-Process "c:\app\myApp.exe /S '/V /qn AllUsers=1 SN=123-456' " -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

Is there any way to combine quotes inside quotes in powershell ? ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like piping the parameter was the way to go: **-PassThru | Wait-Process;** this got us thru the issues. ... ty.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this method

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\app\myApp.exe" -ArgumentList "/S","'/V /qn AllUsers=1 SN=123-456'" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

using `-ArgumentList  "arg1","arg2",...`

for example:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "python" -ArgumentList "-c","print('hello')" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

Output:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     38       3      508       1476       0.02   4932   4 python

hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the whole parameter list as a single string:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\app\myApp.exe  -ArgumentList "/S '/V /qn AllUsers=1 SN=123-456'" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

Or
You can split them

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\app\myApp.exe  -ArgumentList "/S","'/V /qn AllUsers=1 SN=123-456'" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

[More information on start-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Thanks .... for some reason, this works: -ArgumentList "/S","'/V /qn'"   but this does not: -ArgumentList "/S","'/V /qn","AllUsers=1"   it just wont accept the last parameter "foo=123"